# Yii2: Validation rules for whole model object instead of single attributes?

Tags: php, validation, yii2

Consider I have somthing like this:

```
class Dummy extends yii\base\Model {
    public $a;
    public $b;

    public function rules() {
         return [ ??? ];
    }
}
```

How could I create a validation rule considering both attributes $a and $b at the same time? Imagine either $a or $b or both should have a value. If none of them are set I want to get one single validation error like 'Either a or b has to be set'. I think the [when property](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-validator.html#$when-detail) is not helpful here (I could create when conditions for each attribute, checking the other property respectively, but that would create two validation errors).

The example above is a simple one. But it could be much more complex and be dependent on other things as well.

Since [Model::addError()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#addError()-detail) needs an attribute it seems I cannot achieve this. The errors are attribute dependent. So how else could I validate the whole object and e.g. find out if the model object can be saved with its current values. Is there any kind of validation that is on top of the attribute validation? A higher level validation?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you need is a custom validation rule:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['a', 'b', 'c'], 'myCustomRule'],
    ];
}

public function myCustomRule($attribute)
{
    if(!$this->a && !$this->b && !$this->c) {
        $this->addError($attribute, "One of these attributes is required: a, b, c");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't what I expected. This causes 3 errors since the rule is executed per attribute.

Comment: Yes I did it on purpose: User will see three highlighted fields and will know what fields we mean in error message. You can leave only one if you want, still all three will be checked: ```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['a',], 'myCustomRule'],
        [['b', 'c'], 'string'], // or whatever
    ];
}```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#multiple-attributes-errors) one can pass `*` as attribute to [addError($attribute, $error)](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#addError()-detail). However, since the message is not bound to an existing attribute the message needs to be shown with [errorSummary()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activeform.html#errorSummary()-detail) as part of the ActiveForm.

Rules in model

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        [['a', 'b'], 'validateAandB'],
    ];
}
```

Validating method:

```
public function validateAandB($attribute, $params) {
    $this->addError('*', 'a and/or b should have a value.');
}
```

In view with form:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
    <?= $form->errorSummary($model) ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'a') ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, '') ?>
    <?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Actually, it is not required to use `*`, any string is okay. If it is the name of property a validation error will be shown near the input and in the summary, otherwise it is only shown within the summary (summary does not show names of attribute, just the error messages).

Note, the message gets added twice since the validation happens for two attributes. However, since it is added for the same name (here: `*`) and by default only the first message of an attribute gets shown it will be displayed only once.